# array key initial value

Tags: php, arrays, key

i want to set my array key initial value to a certain number.
here is what i have:

```
$tickets=array();
array_push($tickets,"10","20","TBD")

for($i=3; $i<20; $i++)
```

i want my array initial value to start at 3 not 0.

any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're initializing $tickets right there why not use an array literal?

```
$tickets=array(3=>10, 4=>20, 5=>'TBD');
print_r($tickets);
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 20
    [5] => TBD
)
```

edit and btw: This also works with variables in both places, the key and the value. Therefore

```
$x = 5;
$y = 'TBD';
$tickets=array(3=>10, 4=>20, $x=>$y);
print_r($tickets);
```

has the same output as well as

```
$tickets=array( /* initial index here */ 3=>10, 20, 'TDB');
print_r($tickets);
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your first value manually with `$tickets[3]=$value` and PHP will start putting `$tickets[]` at the next index (4, then 5, etc).

Comment: As the documentation clearly says: *Syntax `index => values`, separated by commas, define index and values. `index` may be of type string or integer. (...) If index is an integer, **next generated index** will be the biggest integer `index + 1.`* http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Answer (score 1):

Set `$start_key` to 3, and use [`range()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) to create the set of keys. Use [`array_combine()`](http://us.php.net/array_combine) to combine into the array set up how you want:

```
$tickets = array();
array_push($tickets,"10","20","TBD");
print_r($tickets);
// This is the zero-indexed array that occurs by default:
// Array
// (
//     [0] => 10
//     [1] => 20
//     [2] => TBD
// )

$start_key = 3;
$tickets = array_combine(range($start_key,count($tickets)+($start_key-1)), $tickets);
print_r($tickets);

// Now you have an array whose keys start at 3:
// Array
// (
//     [3] => 10
//     [4] => 20
//     [5] => TBD
// )
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
$tickets = array();
for ($i=3; $i<20; $i++) {
  $tickets[$i] = 'TBD';
}
```

Comment: yup but i want to  access the whole aray from 10, etc. where the initial array[3] = 10, but i am not getting it.
so array[5]=TBD